# I wrote code in React Js, but in localhost it shows error, IDK where is the problem

Tags: reactjs

I wrote this code, and when I want to use that in browser, it shows me parsing error.

```
import OnChange from 'react'

export default function OnChange() {
    let formData = {};
let change = (e) => {
        const { value, name } = e.target;
        formData = { ...formData, [name]: value }
    };
    return (
        <form
            onSubmit={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert(`${formData.lastName} ${formData.fName}`)
            }}
        >
            <label htmlFor="lastName">Last name</label>
            <input
                type="text"
                onChange={change}
                id="lastName"
                name="lastName"
                value={formData.lastName}
            />
              <input
                type="text"
                onChange={change}
                id="lastName"
                name="fName"
                value={formData.fName}
            />
            <button type='submit'>efgrf</button>
        </form>
    )
 
}
```

error:
Parsing error: Identifier 'OnChange' has already been declared

Comment: Ok now I'll try

Comment: It’s literally the first three lines.

Answer (score 0):

You imported `OnChange` as the default react import and then named your component the same. Just change the import of react to be correct.

```
import React from 'react';
```